# How to detect dark mode in Delphi iOS apps

Tags: delphi-10.3-rio, ios-darkmode

How does one detect dark mode in code in a Delphi 10.3 Rio project?

I have a background rectangle that is set to the color White and iOS fails to turn it dark. The TLabel text in a vertical scroll pane does turn to White and that leaves them unreadable on the White background.

Answer (score 0):

There doesn't appear to be a way to detect dark mode in Delphi iOS apps.

To make it possible, I added this function to the bottom of FMX.Platform.iOS.pas

```
function MikesIsDarkModeOn: Boolean;
begin
  Result := not (GetUserInterfaceStyle = UIUserInterfaceStyleLight);   
end;
```

Then I added a timer that checks every two seconds for a change in dark mode and (upon a change) switches the backgrounds of my custom dialogs and list items to white or black. The text was usually (but not always) already switched white/black appropriately for dark mode by Delphi.